# Does it possible in java that daemon thread continue after main thread exited?

Tags: java, multithreading, daemon

I have multithread web application running in Eclipse embedded Tomcat. Some threads are daemon, some not.
After I have run:

```
shutdown.bat
```

I see that some threads finished work, but some remain! Strange that in remaining threads are daemon threads (I have seen in debug view of Eclipse). But it is not possible - I don't see main threads, but see daemon threads! Does it linked to specific of Tomcat web container or it is can be the problem with my web application?
Thanks.
Or it specific of Eclipse embedded Tomcat?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. A program exits when all non-daemon threads have finished.  If main starts a non-daemon thread which is running, having the thread called "main" exit doesn't do anything.

Comment: But may question was about situation that I have seen in debugger - I don't see main thread, but can see daemons (also as not-daemon). Total number of threads decreased on 50% near.

Comment: Even one non-daemon thread (perhaps started by a library which didn't flag the thread as a daemon) will keep the program running.

Comment: My question (please read title) about contradiction with docs - where said that daemons threads cannot exists without main thread.

Comment: @user710818: read Peter's answer. Your assumption is wrong. A daemon thread keeps running while there is **at least 1** non-daemon thread running. Whether the main thread is finished or not is irrelevant. Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon%28boolean%29

Comment: @user710818 There is nothing special about the thread called "main" except it is started for you to run your program.  Nothing special happens when it exits either. When the last non-daemon thread exits, your program starts to shut down.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple proof. If all non-main threads are daemons they all die once the main thread dies:

```
class DaemonTask implements Runnable {

  private final int id;
  private final Thread main;

  DaemonTask(int id, Thread main) {

    this.id = id;
    this.main = main;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {

    while (true) {

      System.out.println((Thread.currentThread().isDaemon() ? "" : "non") + " daemon id = " + id + "; main alive: " + main.isAlive());
      try {
        Thread.sleep(100L * id);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

  Thread t = new Thread(new DaemonTask(i + 1, Thread.currentThread()));
  t.setDaemon(true);
  t.start();
}

System.out.println("main finishing");
```

with an output:

```
main finishing
 daemon id = 6; main alive: true
 daemon id = 3; main alive: true
 daemon id = 2; main alive: true
 daemon id = 10; main alive: true
 daemon id = 9; main alive: false
 daemon id = 8; main alive: false
 daemon id = 4; main alive: false
Process finished with exit code 0
```

If we create and start a non-daemon thread before leaving the main thread:

```
new Thread(new DaemonTask(100, Thread.currentThread())).start();
```

The application will continue running:

```
main finishing
 daemon id = 2; main alive: true
 daemon id = 1; main alive: true
 daemon id = 3; main alive: false
 daemon id = 4; main alive: false
 daemon id = 5; main alive: false
 daemon id = 7; main alive: false
 daemon id = 6; main alive: false
non daemon id = 100; main alive: false
 daemon id = 10; main alive: false
 daemon id = 9; main alive: false
 daemon id = 8; main alive: false
 daemon id = 1; main alive: false
 daemon id = 2; main alive: false
 daemon id = 1; main alive: false
 daemon id = 3; main alive: false
 daemon id = 1; main alive: false
 daemon id = 4; main alive: false
 daemon id = 2; main alive: false
```

Answer (score 1):

You're running a debugger which basically means JVM termination doesn't behave as one would expect it to.

It's quite possible that the developer may want to inspect the daemon threads at the point of JVM termination.

This means that the debugger is effectively the "main" thread in the application, and the debugger would not wish to expose it's inner workings to the UI.  Imagine setting a breakpoint in the debugger code itself...  I see that might confuse things a tad, as you'd lock up your debugging session!

Don't expect this to happen if you're not using a debugger.